# Calling a web service using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm quite new to Node.js. I was experimenting with how to call a service using NodeJS. Would be helpful if could point out the NodeJS equivalent of the code below:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/WebServiceUtility.aspx/CustomOrderService",
  data: "{'id': '2'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (message) {
    ShowPopup(message);
  }
});
```

Any helpful links would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Node.js equivalent to that code can be using jQuery server-side, using other modules, or using the native [HTTP](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html)/[HTTPS](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html) modules. This is how a POST request is done:

```
var http = require('http');
var data = JSON.stringify({
  'id': '2'
});

var options = {
  host: 'host.com',
  port: '80',
  path: '/WebServiceUtility.aspx/CustomOrderService',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  var msg = '';

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    msg += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
    console.log(JSON.parse(msg));
  });
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

This example creates the data payload, which is JSON. It then sets up the HTTP post options, such as host, port, path, headers, etc. The request itself is then set up, which we collect the response for parsing. Then we write the POST data to the request itself, and end the request.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way at the moment is to use the [Request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) (deprecated since 2020). See the page there for lots of examples showing how to do what you want.

If you want to use raw node.js, you'll need to use either [http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) or [https](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html) built-in modules, but you'll have to handle a lot of the encoding and streaming details yourself. Also, be sure to look specifically at the client parts of the documentation, not the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
//--------- Tracking request service                  
factory.trackRequest = function (payload) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        **url: 'https://uat-userauthentication.bdt.kpit.com/'+ 
 'employee/trackRequestStatus'**,
        data: payload
    });
 };

 return factory;
```

I call node js service in angular by UI routing and I used `trackRequest` function in controller.