# Enforce utf8 encoding in call from node to Java

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, utf-8, jetty

I am making a call from a node middle-tier to a Java backend and passing a string as a query param. Everything works great until non-English alphabet character are used (ex: ř,ý). When Java receives these characters it throws:

```
parse exception: org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8!
```

This call works perfectly:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/server/name?name=smith
```

This call fails with the above error:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/server/name?name=sořovský
```

My question involves where to address this issue.
I have found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8) utf8 encoder for node and was thinking about encoding my strings as utf8 before calling my Java layer in the future.
Is that the correct approach or should I be doing something within Java?

Note, this is what my relevant request headers look like:

```
{
  ...
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,el;q=0.6',
  ...
}
```

Comment: If the Java side gives you this error, then the input is most likely not properly encoded in UTF-8 so you have to look at why the Node side is not encoding it properly. Without more details (what does your code look like?) it's very hard to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Jesper, thanks! I added details to my question showing my request options.

Comment: Need more details on what your url (and potential request headers) are.  Can you capture the request headers and add it to your question?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I added the relevant request headers to my question.

Comment: If you take a look at this, they specifically encode the post as UTF-8. Not sure if this is relevant to you however since as others pointed out you didn't include too much detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392744/calling-a-web-service-using-nodejs

Comment: @bruceceng, added further details, namely the `GET` request I make.

Comment: If you were using POST there would be no need to encode. I don't believe that the GET will try and do anything to the url you are posting. you will need to encode the URL arguments. Are you saying that if you encode and change the name to so%C5%99ovsk%C3%BD does that work?

Comment: @MattDionis if my answer help you, click on the bounty ("+50") on my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Save your javascript file to utf8.*

```
var name = "sořovský",
    param1 = encodeURIComponent(name);

var url = "http://localhost:8000/server/name?name=" + param1;

console.log(url);
// http://localhost:8000/server/name?name=so%C5%99ovsk%C3%BD
```

You can see the log with `GET http://localhost:8000/server/name?name=sořovský` :

```
{
  "args": {
    "name": "sořovský"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
    "Accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,el;q=0.6",
    //...
  },
  "url": "http://localhost:8000/server/name?name=sořovský"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GET only supports the ASCII char.set to send other characters you need to percent encode the special chars.

Comment: So it appears my options are changing the `GET` to a `POST` or encoding the the string before passing it as a query param.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Encoding should be your first choice in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the server does not actually use utf-8 as its default encoding (as one might normally asume) but instead uses ISO-8859-1.

Which as can be expected will fail to be decoded using utf-8 (this will only be obvious on non-ascii characters).
I had a very similar problem with a JBoss server.

The solution for me was instead of using request.getParameter() (that automatically converts the parameter using utf-8) to use instead:

```
String name = new String(request.getParameter("name").getBytes("iso-8859-1"),"utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you are sending UTF16 string and treating as UTF-8. All JavaScript strings are UTF16. So it could be that the params are also being sent in as UTF16. 
You could try sending the params via a UTF16 encoder on the Java side of things and then convert it to whatever encoding you want.

Make sure you check the endianness as well of your machine. I hope this helps.

Comment: Also it would be easier to convert the string from UTF16 -> UTF8 in Java than in JavaScript. I am sure there are a ton of APIs.